# Scikit-learn prediction intervals for future values?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

The numbers predicted by my code below are very specific and I do not get any exact matches, but some are pretty close. For example, on a certain date there were actually 388 events and this might predict 397.

- Can I output a range of like 370 - 410? Or see the percentage chance that the value will be between a range? Or should I bin the values and check for accuracy that way?

Code:

```
def make_prediction(label, prediction):
    X = df[[col1, col2, col3]].values
    y = df[label].values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
    X_train.shape, X_test.shape
    clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    output = clf.predict(X)
    result = np.c_[X, output]
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[col1, col2, col3, prediction])
    return df_result
```

So the code above places a value for each row (which is a date in this case but I number them from 1 onward based on the first value in the data set. How do I predict future values? When I run the code above I only get the predicted values for existing data, how can I use that model on other data sets or input future dates?

Comment: Based on the output, why cant you have a wrapper which convert that to range?

Comment: How though? This is my first time using Scikit-learn and I used a few notebooks and blogs I found online to mirror my code. They used classification though, so they were able to check if their prediction matched reality. My predictions don't match exactly though. I'm trying to get to the point where I can forecast next weeks events per weekday based on the last few months of daily historical data. This is a time series analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you require binning on top of predicted values, you can use pandas [`cut()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) as follows:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([270,201,375,370,410,510], columns=['prediction'])

In [3]: bins = [0,370,420,600]

In [4]: group_labels = ['(0-370]', '(371-420]', '(421-600]']

In [5]: df['prediction_range'] = pd.cut(df.prediction, bins, labels=group_labels)

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   prediction prediction_range
0         270          (0-370]
1         201          (0-370]
2         375        (371-420]
3         370          (0-370]
4         410        (371-420]
5         510        (421-600]
```

Reference: [Binning Data In Pandas](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_binning_data.html)